# is there any option print 0 if array position is null?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 arrays 1 have 4 values and the other have 3 values like below

**html part**

```
<input id="answer" type="text" name="answer">
<input id="correct" type="checkbox" name="ifcorrect[]">

<input id="answer" type="text" name="answer">
<input id="correct" type="checkbox" name="ifcorrect[]">

<input id="answer" type="text" name="answer">
<input id="correct" type="checkbox" name="ifcorrect[]">
```

i am expecting below result:

```
Answer Field 1 Value:: ABCD    Checkbox: Checked =>  Value: 1
Answer Field 2 Value:: EFG     Checkbox: UnChecked =>  Value: 0
Answer Field 2 Value:: HIJ     Checkbox: Checked =>  Value: 1
```

```
$arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];   
$arr2 = ['1', '2', '3'];

foreach ($arr as $ar => $key) {

   echo $key;

   if (!empty($arr2[$ar]))
      echo $arr2[$ar];

   echo "<br>";
}
```

current result of this array is:

```
a1 
b2
c3
d
```

but i want result like this

t result of this array is:

```
a1 
b
c2
d3
```

Comment: any logic to expect that result?

Comment: actually i have 3 input fields whiche are filled with values and 3 checkboxes 1st and 3rd checkbox is selected 2nd is unselect

when i am trying to insert in db it sends the wrong values.
I am expecting to send first input value with first checkbox and for example if second chkbox is not selected than send 0 or null

Comment: Ok, so you're essentially asking the wrong question in your actual post. Please edit that and include relevant code. This is a classic XY problem -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: can you post your html code

Comment: please edit your question and add html part also

Comment: Something is missing here on logic or expected behaviour. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: please check now. sorry to bother you actually i am intern and don't have idea how to solve this :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `$request->has('')` method in laravel. For example:

```
//if 'lorem' checkbox not selected, add a variable to the request and set it to 0
if (!$request->has('lorem')) $request->request->add(['lorem' => 0]);
```

In `php`, you can try this:

```
if(empty($array[0])) $array[0]=0;
```

Try this, if you want to check all the items in an `array`:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){
  if(empty($array[$i])) $array[$i]=0;
}
```

Comment: i think nested lopp required to match 2 arrays and if position of any array is null it will add 0 ? but i don't know how to do t his